# Is there any way to print errors in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to print error on firebase? **not create another `collection` and create `document`**

**Example:** I called cloud function. but when cloud function failed we can't find which error/error code. Now, I debug application and run cloud function again check with my console. Is there any way to print in firebase?

```
 if (result.data['success']) {
    finalize();
  } else if (result.data['errorCode'] == 1003) {
      print(result.data['errorMessage']);
  } else {
      print(result.data['errorMessage']);
  }
} on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
  print(e);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

And also other errors. api call errors etc

Comment: What do you mean by 'print in firebase'? What is your expected outcome? Since you are tracing this on the flutter code side I assumed you want to add this stack traces to your database, however you mentioned 'not create another collection and create document'. So I am a little confused on what you expecting.

Comment: @ralemos what is stack trace mean?

Comment: @ralemos how to create stack trace? using this api https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

Every error produced by function is stored in `Firebase Dashboard -> Function -> Logs (tab)`. Moreover, when you create your own function, every console.log() is logged there.

Comment: I just add example, what about other http call errors? I just `print()`